# rolling back wrong encoded string

Tags: c#, string, utf-8, streamreader

I have a really bad problem. I have a lot of records in database which are in Persian language. For some reasons, I load them, make some changes to them (by HtmlAgilityPack), and then save them back to db. But all strings gone to `?????????????` symbols. Is there any way to getting them back? Here is my code snippet:

```
private void SomeStartMethod(){
    var str = ReadFromDb();
    str = MakeChanges(str);
    SaveToDbAgain(str);
}

private string MakeChanges(string contentHtml) {
    var reader = new StringReader(contentHtml);

    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.Load(reader);
    var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
    if (nodes == null || !nodes.Any())
        return contentHtml;
    foreach (var link in nodes) {
        // do some stuffs here...
    }

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
        doc.Save(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream /* here was my mistake, I forgot to put , Encoding.UTF8 here */);
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, the characters have been replaced by the `?` when C#/.NET couldn't load them correctly. You'll need to restore the strings from another copy of the data (if available.)

Comment: You say your error was forgetting to specify Encoding.UTF8 when you created the StreamReader object, but this seems to indicate that that should be defult: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfzs7at%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @RenniePet So may be I am wrong and I should set HtmlDocument encoding? However, what can I do now? do you have any idea please?

Comment: Sorry, no, wish I did. (Some kinds of databases maintain a transaction log that allow rollbacks, but I assume you know that.)

Comment: @RenniePet ): ): The `Restore/Transaction Log` menu item is unavailable. I'm using a shared hosting.

Comment: You are totally sure the data has become corrupted? Those question marks you're seeing are not due to viewing the data in an ASCII-only viewer?

Comment: @RenniePet well it seems they are corrupted ): I'm using the db in a website. also when I get `var b =Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txt);`, it seems all bytes have value 63. I'll get killed. Thank you for your help. But I think I have no option.

Comment: Change your name and join the French Foreign Legion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60423/discussion-between-javad-amiry-and-renniepet).